# calorie counting?

Tags: weight-loss

I am trying to lose fat so I'm creating a 500 calorie deficit per day. I want my calorie intake to be pretty accurate, but the problem is that I'm in college and I can't cook my own foods. Which means I have to visually estimate how many calories I eat. Should I use a food scale to measure my food before I eat? I know the basic tricks to visually measuring food servings, (like a deck of cards=3 oz meat) but it can be innacurate. For example, if I eat 4 pieces of chicken, and I think its 3 oz each, but turns out to be 3.5 oz, I'm off by 2 oz or about 100 calories. If I miscalculate for other foods as well, I could be off by hundreds of calories by the end of the day.

Comment: I think it's funny how people are 'unable' to cook their own food. What's the reason? No time? Can't cook? No store available? There are many reasons for cooking your own food being difficult, but there're solutions for all of them. If you can live with it is a different question, that's when you have to set priorities. Other than taking control over what you eat, I don't see a good way to 'guesstimate' your calories consistently.

Comment: If he's in a dorm at college, there is no kitchen available to him for cooking.  But as you say, there are solutions.  One of them is seeing if you can get nutritional info from the campus cafeteria if that's where you're getting the most of your food.

Comment: I agree that cooking is the best way to count calories. I would use the nutritional information from the cafeteria, except that they don't have that information. The best I can do is look it up online and visually estimate portion sizes. But I feel like i'm too inaccurate

Comment: Just dropping caloric intake is no guarantee that you'll lose fat.

Comment: I agree, it could be muscle loss. I'm following a weight lifting program like 5x5 to preserve muscle mass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question you ask, yes, weighing your food is a good idea if you're serious. More than accuracy, the knowledge of the amounts that you are eating is important when you later inevitably revisit and reevaluate your plan. You will *know* if it's the plan that needs changing if you're not getting the desired results, shedding doubt that the blame lies in your estimation skills. **However**, doing this for every meal for the foreseeable future is not going to be fun. Therefore I suggest making a game out of guessing the amounts before measuring them for the first week or two, while you're enthusiastic, such that you calibrate your own estimations. If you just measure you'll get better at estimating too but it'll take longer. At any rate, once you're getting within your acceptable margin of error you can quit using the scale. This is particularly effective if there are only a handful of dishes at your dining hall which you frequent.

And also something to consider outside the direct question:
"A Calorie's a Calorie" to an extent yes but this is an incomplete way to devise an eating plan. Make sure to do your research on meal timings (intermittent fasting vs 6 meals/day) and caloric intake composition (this is extremely important). These affect both your body's adaptations to caloric restriction and your psychology (keeping you full & content). I won't provide an essay of unsolicited advice but do look into these if you haven't already and if you *do* want my advice on it just ask :)

Comment: Thanks. Yea I read about intermittent fasting and different eating styles, right now i'm trying to do something like leangains. I try to eat higher carbs on workout days, and high protein every day, etc. Have you seen any research about caloric intake and muscle growth/loss? I know that on a severe caloric deficit, your nitrogen balance will be negative no matter how much protein you eat, so caloric surplus helps muscle growth. The question is, just how much of a surplus do you need? people estimate 250cal/day, or 3500/2weeks but that assumes that 1 lb muscle=1 lb fat, which is incorrect

Comment: That's great, I can speak from personal experience to the efficacy of a leangains-style method. The question you ask needs some qualification (i.e. surplus needed for what?) but in general there are a few solutions to gaining muscle while losing fat, if that's what you're asking. Note that whatever you do, muscle gain will always be slower while simultaneously dropping fat but it **is possible** to do so (I've done it). The more you eat, the faster you can gain muscle but the slower you will lose fat.

Comment: My recommendation is keep protein intake high and cut calories and carbs as you're planning and your body will take care of the rest. There's a long debate on how much protein is the right amount, and it obviously depends on how hard you strength train. A happy safe high-middle number would be between .8g/lbLBM and 1g/lbLBM where lbLBM is your lean body weight in pounds. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your health conscious then you have to be very careful towards the calorie that your taken daily.First of all you have to know that how many calories you need on each day to maintain your health.Its an old saying that Health is Wealth.So you need to be raise your awareness about what your body needs.You have to keep the knowledge of how much calorie are in the food and drinks taken by you in each day.The weight loss resources have the tools to count the calorie you needed in a day.

Answer (score 0):

Using a scale certainly helps, both to improve accuracy when you use it, and to improve your estimations when you can't.

Don't worry too much about accuracy. If you estimate honestly, you'll err on both sides with equal likelihood, and the errors should cancel out.